# Error 404 not found usando el método DELETE con fetch JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, nodejs, apache

Estoy creando una página web usando JSON API REST, junto con XAMPP con el servidor apache. La cosa es que, hasta ahora, he estado usando el método DELETE, y todo bien. Pero ahora, estoy realmente atascado, porque estoy haciendo un método DELETE simple, y me sigue devolviendo "404 Not found", cuando obviamente he comprobado varias veces que el recurso que quiero eliminar existe en el archivo JSON. ¿Qué está ocurriendo exactamente? Me está volviendo loco ... Muchas gracias de antemano

Os dejo por aquí EL código JS:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:3000/votes?photoId=${id}&userId=${userId}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer' + getToken(),

        }
    });
```

Y el fichero JSON del que quiero obtener el recurso:

```
 "votes": [
{
  "photoId": "4",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 2
},
{
  "photoId": "2",
  "userId": "7",
  "id": 4
},
{
  "photoId": "5",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 5
},
{
  "photoId": "3",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 6
},
{
  "photoId": "3",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 7
},
{
  "photoId": "1",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 8
},
{
  "photoId": "2",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 12
},
{
  "photoId": "3",
  "userId": "7",
  "id": 14
},
{
  "photoId": "1",
  "userId": "7",
  "id": 15
},
{
  "photoId": "5",
  "userId": "7",
  "id": 16
},
{
  "photoId": "3",
  "userId": "11",
  "id": 17
},
{
  "photoId": "1",
  "userId": "11",
  "id": 18
},
{
  "photoId": "4",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 19
},
{
  "photoId": "2",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 20
},
{
  "photoId": "1",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 21
},
{
  "photoId": "6",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 22
},
{
  "photoId": "6",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 23
}
```

],

Comment: ¿El servidor está sirviendo un *endpoint* en `/votes` de tipo DELETE? ¿Y si haces una llamada des de Postman o algo parecido funciona?

Comment: Podrías añadir tu código del endpoint

Comment: Además de que hace falta añadir la cabecera `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: @VRoxa  el servidor está en mi propia máquina, es un api rest de json. No sé a a que te refieres con endpoint, soy un poco novato.

Comment: Ya probé añadiendo la cabecera, fue lo primero que hice de hecho, y no iba